# Add moderator-only flag to tags API?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Currently there is no way to distinguish between normal and moderator only tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags methods now return `restricted_to` and `fulfills_required` (I know you didn't ask for the second one, but it was also missing).

[Update docs.](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/1/tags?help)

`restricted_to` will be set to a "minimum" user type if appropriate, and `fulfills_required` will be set to true if it is one of the tags of which at least one must appear on a question.